# Timestamp, WS-Security issue on client

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services, ws-security

I'm receiving an error when I'm attempting to consume a web service:

```
 Cannot read the token from the 'Timestamp' element with the 'http://docs.oasis-     open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd' namespace for BinarySecretSecurityToken, with a '' ValueType.
```

Not quite sure

The client is an asp.net web application, making a call. From Wireshark, one can see the post going in, and the response coming back, but then it errors out like this.

To give some background, this is a WCF calling on a java served web service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to add a security timestamp soap header to the message. Look at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9621964/wcf-interop-no-timestamp-is-available-in-security-header-to-do-replay-detection/9623162#9623162) where they had the opposite problem but it may be helpful to look at their configuration. Also, you may save yourself some grief if you can use one of the WCF [Interop Express](http://wcf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WCF%20Express%20Interop%20Bindings) bindings for accessing a java service implementing WS-Security.

Comment: I am adding a security timestamp to the request. This appears to be occurring on the response. Could this be related to the binding, as I'm utilizing basichttpbinding. However, the service requires SOAP 1.1...

Comment: If you look at the WCF config XML in the question I referenced in my answer, you'll see they are configuring a custom binding instead of using basicHttpBinding. It's likely they're not using basicHttpBinding because it does not support most of the ws-* standards.

Comment: I think this gives me enough direction to adjust my code accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: Alright, created a custom binding, still getting this same error. Any ideas?

Comment: You could create a dummy WCF *service* that is configured like your client is now. Code and configure it so you can call it successfully with the client as-is. Compare the soap message that the java service returns against what the dummy WCF service returns. The problem is definitely in what WCF is expecting for the structure of the soap headers that are used to implement the ws-security standard.

Comment: Because the service is being encrypted, it's difficult to tell what's being missed. Is there a way to ignore the timestamp on the client side from the response? I am receiving the response, but this piece seems to be the hangup.

Comment: You can view encrypted messages with the built-in [WCF message tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064.aspx) capability. You need to configure message tracing for the **Service** level. This [blog post](http://dotnetrobert.com/?q=node/215) has a short overview of message tracing.

Comment: After tracing this, it appears that WCF creates the timestamp within the security tag, but unencrypted. When the server responds, the timestamp is created within the signature block, encrypted. When WCF goes to look for the timestamp, it blows up, because for all it knows, it doesn't exist.

The timestamp is required by the server, but is there a way I can insert the timestamp in to the signature?

Comment: I'd first try intercepting the response message using the WCF [message inspection](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/04/19/wcf-extensibility-message-inspectors.aspx) extension and inject the expected timestamp. Off the top of my head, I don't know of any other approach to do this. Good luck!

Comment: The solution that we did was just contact the service provider and have a matter corrected. It really isn't a solution, but it fixed our issue.